# Tensorflow dense layers worse than keras sequential

Tags: keras, tensorflow

I try to train an agent on the inverse-pendulum (similar to cart-pole) problem, which is a benchmark of reinforcement learning. I use neural-fitted-Q-iteration algorithm which uses a multi-layer neural network to evaluate the Q function.

I use Keras.Sequential and tf.layers.dense to build the neural network repectively, and leave all other things to be the same. However, Keras gives me a good results and tensorflow does not. In fact, tensorflow doesn't work at all with its loss being increasing and the agent learns nothing from the training.

Here I present the code for Keras as follows

```
def build_model():
    model = Sequential()
    model.add(Dense(5, input_dim=3))
    model.add(Activation('sigmoid'))
    model.add(Dense(5))
    model.add(Activation('sigmoid'))
    model.add(Dense(1))
    model.add(Activation('sigmoid'))
    adam = Adam(lr=1E-3)
    model.compile(loss='mean_squared_error', optimizer=adam)
    return model
```

and the tensorflow version is

```
class NFQ_fit(object):
"""
neural network approximator for NFQ iteration
"""

def __init__(self, sess, N_feature, learning_rate=1E-3, batch_size=100):

    self.sess = sess
    self.N_feature = N_feature
    self.learning_rate = learning_rate
    self.batch_size = batch_size

    # DNN structure
    self.inputs = tf.placeholder(tf.float32, [None, N_feature], 'inputs')
    self.labels = tf.placeholder(tf.float32, [None, 1], 'labels')
    self.l1 = tf.layers.dense(inputs=self.inputs,
                         units=5,
                         activation=tf.sigmoid,
                         use_bias=True,
                         kernel_initializer=tf.truncated_normal_initializer(0.0, 1E-2),
                         bias_initializer=tf.constant_initializer(0.0),
                         kernel_regularizer=tf.contrib.layers.l2_regularizer(1E-4),
                         name='hidden-layer-1')
    self.l2 = tf.layers.dense(inputs=self.l1,
                         units=5,
                         activation=tf.sigmoid,
                         use_bias=True,
                         kernel_initializer=tf.truncated_normal_initializer(0.0, 1E-2),
                         bias_initializer=tf.constant_initializer(0.0),
                         kernel_regularizer=tf.contrib.layers.l2_regularizer(1E-4),
                         name='hidden-layer-2')
    self.outputs = tf.layers.dense(inputs=self.l2,
                                   units=1,
                                   activation=tf.sigmoid,
                                   use_bias=True,
                                   kernel_initializer=tf.truncated_normal_initializer(0.0, 1E-2),
                                   bias_initializer=tf.constant_initializer(0.0),
                                   kernel_regularizer=tf.contrib.layers.l2_regularizer(1E-4),
                                   name='outputs')
    # optimization
    # self.mean_loss = tf.losses.mean_squared_error(self.labels, self.outputs)
    self.mean_loss = tf.reduce_mean(tf.square(self.labels-self.outputs))
    self.regularization_loss = tf.losses.get_regularization_loss()
    self.loss = self.mean_loss # + self.regularization_loss
    self.train_op = tf.train.AdamOptimizer(learning_rate=self.learning_rate).minimize(self.loss)
```

The two models are the same. Both of them has two hidden layers with the same dimension. I expect that the problems may come from the kernel initialization but I don't know how to fix it.